# How to get DISTINCT row from INNER JOIN Query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I've been working on a school management project. A teacher has multiple subjects, I need to display only one subject in query but I get all the subjects that a teacher has. Now I need only one record for Teacher 2 (TeacherId =2 has two subjects (English & Math) from the above screenshot's query. English or Math any of them will do.

Query in Text:

```
SELECT        dbo.Teacher.TeacherId, dbo.Teacher.TeacherName, dbo.Gender.Gender, dbo.Teacher.DOB, ISNULL(dbo.Subject.Subject, 'No Subject') AS Subject, 
                         dbo.Teacher.Contact, dbo.Teacher.Address, dbo.Teacher.Email, dbo.Teacher.Photo
FROM            dbo.Subject INNER JOIN
                         dbo.TeacherSubject ON dbo.Subject.SubjectId = dbo.TeacherSubject.SubjectId RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.Teacher INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Gender ON dbo.Teacher.Gender = dbo.Gender.GenderId ON dbo.TeacherSubject.TeacherId = dbo.Teacher.TeacherId
```

Thanks in advance for helping me a lot.

Comment: Can you please post your query as text?

Comment: You already have distinct records in your results. The ID 2 has the same teacher teaching different subjects. Math and English

Comment: when you are saying "English or Math any of them will do" in above query that means you have not understood the requirement correctly or your approach is wrong.Why do you want to join with Subject table if only teacher detail is require.Even if you join with subject table then there should good technical reason to choose among "English or Math".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to join just one subject per teacher in the first place. So join with an aggregate:

```
select
  t.teacherid, 
  t.teachername, 
  g.gender, 
  t.dob, 
  coalesce(s.subject, 'no subject') as subject, 
  t.contact, 
  t.address, 
  t.email, 
  t.photo
from teacher t
join gender g on g.genderid = t.gender
left join 
(
   select teacherid, max(subjectid) as max_subjectid
   from teachersubject
   group by teacherid
) ts on ts.teacherid = t.teacherid
left join subject s on s.subjectid = ts.max_subjectid;
```

Answer (score 2):

Take your query add Row_Number() statement as another column and put in the CTE your entire query

```
WITH CTE AS
(
Select *,Row_Number()OVER(PARTITION BY SUBJECT ORDER BY 1 DESC)RN from Table
)
Select * from CTE WHERE RN = 1
```

OR

TRY LIKE THIS

```
Select * from Dbo.Subject
INNER JOIN (Select DISTINCT ISNULL(MAX(Subjectname,'NoSubject') As Subject FROM TeacherSubject)As Subjectname
ON Subjectname.SubjectID = Subject.SubjectID
```

Answer (score 1):

Make use of distinct clause. This should work for you. In your case place distinct between Select and dbo.Teacher.TeacherId (in the first line).